# How to build openssl-sys for android?

Tags: rust, libgit2, git2-rs

I wrote a program that uses the git2 library and it compiled fine on my local machine (Macbook M2,openssl installed using brew), but when I tried to compile the program for Android, it gave me an "error: failed to run custom build command for 'openssl-sys v0.9.90'"

I tried to build openssl for android, but i don't know how to build it and there are also outdated tutorials

I tried adding openssl to PATH but to no help
Also I tried to build it in docker(ubuntu),but it still cannot build openssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used openssl from crate, which automatically compiles a platform-specific and statically linked version of openssl. I don't know if I'm right, I'm just a beginner
But it does solve the problem

```
[dependencies]
openssl = { version = "*", features = ["vendored"] }
```

Add in your `Cargo.toml`